# Validation Rule on Lead Conversion - Best Practice

Tags: validation-rule, bestpractice, process

I have a **Validation Rule** on the **Lead Object**, to prevent the users from converting a Lead without filling in certain fields. The Validation works, but I want now to only requests those fields, **if the Account is a new Account**.

To mention, **the same fields** are **marked as required** on the **Account Page Layout**.

I have also have a Validation on Contact (for Email) and Account (Billing Address) and it only fires on the Lead Conversion, if converting into a new Account and Contact, or if the existent records don't have the info filled in already.(**Setting**: **Require Validation for Converted Leads = TRUE**)

In order to enforce **the Validation only for new Accounts**, what's the best practice to keep it clean? **To create the Validation on the Account**, but for the user journey creating only a new Account will be confusing as no fields will appear required (unless I am leaving them required on the Page Layout also), or **create a checkbox on Lead and Account**, **map the fields**, **bypass the validation** and create a **workflow to untick the checkbox on the Account**, to enforce Validation for new Accounts creation?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.

Thanks.